# ngFor loop content disapears when leaving page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Angular and Ionic. I am looping through an array of content that is store in my Firestore database. When the app recompiles and loads, then I go to the settings page (that's where the loop is happening), I see the array of content just fine. I can update it on Firestore and it will update in real time in the app. It's all good here. But if I click "Back" (because Settings is being visited using "navPush"), then click on the Settings page again, the whole loop content will be gone.

Stuff is still in the database just fine. I have to recompile the project to make the content appear again. But once again, as soon as I leave that settings page, and come back, the content will be gone.

Here's my code:

HTML Settings page (main code for the loop):

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let setting of settings">
        <ion-icon item-start color="light-grey" name="archive"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{ setting.name }}</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle (ionChange)="onToggle($event, setting)" [checked]="setting.state"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

That Settings page TS file:

```
import { Settings } from './../../../models/settings';
import { DashboardSettingsService } from './../../../services/settings';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard-settings',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard-settings.html',
})
export class DashboardSettingsPage implements OnInit {


  settings: Settings[];
  checkStateToggle: boolean;
  checkedSetting: Settings;

  constructor(public dashboardSettingsService: DashboardSettingsService) {
    this.dashboardSettingsService.getSettings().subscribe(setting => {
      this.settings = setting;
      console.log(setting.state);
    })
  }

  onToggle(event, setting: Settings) {
    this.dashboardSettingsService.setBackground(setting);
  }

}
```

And my Settings Service file (the DashboardSettingsService import):

```
import { Settings } from './../models/settings';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class DashboardSettingsService implements OnInit {

  settings: Observable<Settings[]>;
  settingsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Settings>;
  settingDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Settings>;

    public checkedSetting = false;

  setBackground(setting: Settings) {
    if (this.checkedSetting == true) {
      this.checkedSetting = false;
    } else if(this.checkedSetting == false) {
      this.checkedSetting = true;
    };
    this.settingDoc = this.afs.doc(`settings/${setting.id}`);
    this.settingDoc.update({state: this.checkedSetting});
    console.log(setting);
  }

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.settingsCollection = this.afs.collection('settings');
    this.settings = this.settingsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Settings;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
  });

}
isChecked() {
  return this.checkedSetting;
}

    getSettings() {
      return this.settings;
    }

    updateSetting(setting: Settings) {
      this.settingDoc = this.afs.doc(`settings/${setting.id}`);
      this.settingDoc.update({ state: checkedSetting });
    }

}
```

Any idea what is causing that?
My loop was in a custom component before, so I tried putting it directly in the Dashboard Settings Page, but it's still not working. I have no idea what to check here. I tried putting the :

```
this.dashboardSettingsService.getSettings().subscribe(setting => {
  this.settings = setting;
})
```

...part in an ngOninit method instead, or even ionViewWillLoad, and others, but it's not working either.

I am using Ionic latest version (3+) and same for Angular (5)

Thank you!

Comment: It's better if you could put it in a lifecycle method, say oinViewDIdLoad or ionViewDidEnter or something

Comment: I tried this too and I cannot make it work correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: So is it happening only once? Or any number of times after the first push?

Comment: I mean there is a toggle event there, and i didn't get what you are doing with it

Comment: When the app loads for the first time after compiling, and I click on the Settings page, I am being pushed there, and I will see the data from the database correctly in the ngFor section. But if I click the "Back" link, and come back to the page, it won't be appearing anymore. And won't be there until I recompile the app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Code you posted i have observed two findings that might be the potential cause for the issue ,

1. Calling of the Service method in the constructor :

When your setting component is created , then that constructor will be called but but if you were relying on properties or data from child components actions to take place like navigating to the Setting page so move your constructor to any of the life cycle hooks.

```
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Component content has been initialized
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    // Component content has been Checked
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Component views are initialized
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // Component views have been checked
  }
```

Even though you add your service calling method in the life cycle events but it will be called only once as you were subscribing your service method in the constructor of the Settings service file . so just try to change your service file as follows :

```
getSettings() {
     this.settingsCollection = this.afs.collection('settings');
     this.settingsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Settings;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
  });


    }
```

**Update :**

Try to change the Getsettings as follows and please do update your question with the latest changes

```
getSettings() {


   this.settingsCollection = this.afs.collection('settings');
 return this.settingsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Settings;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
  });


    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. I did what you said (switching code from Constructor to the "getSettings" method), but now I get "Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" error. I guess that now, the Dashboard-Settings page tries to subscribe to something not defined since it's now initialized in with the constructor anymore? Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: @iarin555 can you update the question after applying the latest changes

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now! So basically, I had to return the snapshotChanges to make sure it is being populated every time the settings are being fetched from the database? Thanks again! (Btw, I can award the bounty only in 3 hours, will do later :)

Comment: Not disputing that this solution will work, but depending on the load you're expecting you may want to cache the settings rather than hitting the dB every time a new component is created.

Comment: @Steveland83 yes, that is something that need to be handle at the architecutural level and implementation concerns but for the problem OP posted this would be the solution.

Comment: @Iarin555 , in short yes , but i would recommend to see a way to update those changes rather than going to db on every time the component is called

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I suspect the subscription to the settings observable `settings: Observable<Settings[]>` could be to blame. This may work on the first load because the `DashboardSettingsService` is being created and injected, therefore loading the settings, and then emitting an item (causing your subscription event in `DashboardSettingsPage` to fire).

On the second page load, `DashboardSettingsService` already exists (services are created as singletons by default) - this means that the constructor does not get called (which is where you set up your observable) and therefore it does not emit a new settings object for your component.

Because the Observable does not emit anything, the following event will not be fired, meaning your local settings object is never populated:

`this.dashboardSettingsService.getSettings().subscribe(setting => {
      this.settings = setting;
      console.log(setting.state);
    })`

You could refactor your service with a method that provides the latest (cached) settings object, or a new Observable (dont forget to unsubscribe!!), rather than creating a single Observable which will only be triggered by creation or changes to the underlying storage object.

Here's a simple example that doesnt change your method signature.

```
import { Settings } from './../models/settings';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()

export class DashboardSettingsService implements OnInit {

  settings: Observable<Settings[]>;
  cachedSettings: Settings[];
  settingsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Settings>;
  settingDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Settings>;

  public checkedSetting = false;

  setBackground(setting: Settings) {
    if (this.checkedSetting == true) {
      this.checkedSetting = false;
    } else if(this.checkedSetting == false) {
      this.checkedSetting = true;
    };
    this.settingDoc = this.afs.doc(`settings/${setting.id}`);
    this.settingDoc.update({state: this.checkedSetting});
    console.log(setting);
  }

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.settingsCollection = this.afs.collection('settings');
    this.settings = this.settingsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Settings;
          data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          this.cachedSettings = data;
          return data;
        });
     }); 
   }

  isChecked() {
    return this.checkedSetting;
  }

  getSettings() {
    return Observable.of(this.cachedSettings);
  }

  updateSetting(setting: Settings) {
    this.settingDoc = this.afs.doc(`settings/${setting.id}`);
    this.settingDoc.update({ state: checkedSetting });
  }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I tried and if I update the content directly in the Firestore database, when the loop is empty, the content will re-appear. So like you said, it seems like the object is populated only when the database is updated. Could you guide me on what code I should use to achieve what you are saying? I'm not sure on how it should be done. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about storing the settings value in your `DashboardSettingsService` with `storage.set` on the creation and populating the `settingsPage` for the second time with `storage.get`. And in that way, data change in the database can be reflected in the `settingsPage` and also even if there is no change in the data from database can be reflected in the page.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Can you help me a bit telling me what I should try to use "get" and "set" instead? Are we talking about the "snapshotChanges" part that needs to be changed?

Comment: @larin555 - Added a full example.

Comment: Regarding Kevins suggestion to use `storage.get` (did you mean `localStorage.getItem()` ?) you could do something like that - but since the service is a singleton there is no need to do this - variables in the class will be maintained for the session.